# dropDownDefaultValue in dijit DateTextBox broken?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

as the documentation of the dijit DateTextBox says I want to set the Date the user sees when he opens the dropdown. I don't want to put the date in the value property of the DateTextBox. In my application the date is optional but when it's used other fields need to be filled, too.

The value I want to show in the dropDownDefaultValue depends on other dates. If the other date is in 2006 I set the range to 2006 so the user is unable to select a date after 2006. Without a selected default date it is realy annoying cause it's always today.

So here's a fiddle I tried to set the dropDownDefaultValue [fiddle`<div  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="dropDownDefaultValue:'2010-10-12'"></div>`](https://jsfiddle.net/ekL2Lgj1/)
I'm using the dijit/dateTextBox documented here [documentation DateTextBox](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox)

Any ideas why It's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dropDownDefaultValue` is supposed to be an object, not a string.

You have to do it like that:

```
  <div  data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" data-dojo-props="dropDownDefaultValue: new Date(2012,10,12)"></div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/q4L1j861/

Comment: yeah that's it. Thought dojo get's it automaticaly. :)